# Problem setting-up RPi as WiFi hostspot with Ralink RT3070

Tags: wifi, drivers

I am trying to set-up my RPi as a wireless hotspot so I can control it wirelessly from my laptop. There are many guides around that are referred to in these forums as well however I keep on having the same problem. I followed all the steps at http://jacobsalmela.com/raspberry-pi-and-routing-turning-a-pi-into-a-router and http://elinux.org/RPI-Wireless-Hotspot until `sudo service hostapd restart` but then get the error:

```
[FAIL] Starting advanced IEEE 802.11 management: hostapd failed!
```

Then by typing in `sudo hostapd -d /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf` I get:

```
Line 2: invalid/unknown driver 'nl180211'
```

I also followed the guide by not_the_pi_guy http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=25921 and a similar other guide http://www.jenssegers.be/blog/43/Realtek-RTL8188-based-access-point-on-Raspberry-Pi that explain how to install a different hostapd file to work with Ralink wifi adapter but still don't get it to work..

I have now already spent 5 hours trying to get this to work and am totally lost what to do. If anyone has any advice that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error message

```
    Line 2: invalid/unknown driver 'nl180211'
```

The driver is called nl80211, not nl180211: just remove the 1 from the name in the hostapd file.